# tkinter open a python program from a master window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have little python programs to create html, for example insertMedia.py: this takes the name of the media file, puts it in the html code string and writes it to the output file.

insertMedia.py uses tkinter. I have a window with the buttons "insert audio" and 'insert video".

insertMedia.py works well, no problems. Also, I have some more "makehtml" programs, each for a specific task.

I want to have a master window, with buttons, or maybe a menu item for each "makehtml" program.

How can I open and run insertMedia.py from a master window?

Should I put all the "makehtml" programs in a module and import the module?

This code from Bryan Oakley, here in stackoverflow, opens a new window. Can it be modified to open my insertMedia.py?

```
import Tkinter as tk

def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

To show you just the priciple of a common way to do this.

Frist you create a main file with your stuff in main.py wich looks like for exampel:

***main.py***

```
import tkinter as tk
import Mod1

root = tk.Tk()


def callback():
    m1 = Mod1.Model(root, var='my_html')    
b = tk.Button(text='click me', command=callback)
b.grid(column=0,row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Then you are creating another script with your Toplevel and stuff in it like this:
***Mod1.py***

```
from __main__ import tk

class Model(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, var=None):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.configure(bg="red", width=300, height=300)

        b=tk.Button(self,text='print html', command=lambda:print(var))
        b.pack()
```

So what I did here is to create another script with a class with the parent class tk.Toplevel. This means the class becomes a subclass of it. We pass the parameter master wich is root, as you can see in the main.py to get a reference through the interface.

Also note that we imported the Mod1 script and later we reference the Model by Mod1.Model(). You could just import the Model with `from Mod1 import Model` instead of import Mod1. Also we imported from the **main** script the reference of tk to work with.

To pass a variabel like a string of your html, you can pass var through the interface. I made it like a kwarg(keyword argument), to make it necessary for the class to initialize you have to delete `=None` wich is a default vaulue.

Thats all we need to work it out. Have fun!

For more complex stuff you also could do a dictionary with keys and values.

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import Mod1

root = tk.Tk()


def callback():
    data_dict = {'key a':'value a','key b':'value b'} 
    m1 = Mod1.Model(root, dct= data_dict)    
b = tk.Button(text='click me', command=callback)
b.grid(column=0,row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

and **Mod1.py**

```
from __main__ import tk

class Model(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, dct=None):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.configure(bg="red", width=300, height=300)

        b=tk.Button(self,text='print html', command=lambda:print(dct['key a']))
        b.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had problems: I made main.py and Mod1.py then I ran Mod1.py got this: pedro@pedro-512ssd:~/myPython/tkinter$ ./Mod1.py
from: can't read /var/mail/__main__
./Mod1.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./Mod1.py: line 3: `class Model(tk.Toplevel):'
If I run main.py I have to restart the computer! The mouse pointer is gone! Could you possibly put some more meat on these skinny bones please?

Comment: I dont work with html, so I cant give you a full exampel of it. But if you are working with variabels like I assume since there is "can't read/var/mail/.." You do need to pass all the variabels to the script you are working with. I will update my answer to show you how to solve this.

Comment: Let me know if something missing.

Comment: I think the problem is the path variable: Python can't find your main.py What I did was make a module, guiHTML.py I made sure it is in the system path, then I import that file in my master window. All my "makehtml" functions are in the module. Seems to work, even if it is not the best way!

Comment: You've right, I forgot to mention that. Python is searching for modules in the path where python is installed and in the directory of the current working file. I will update my answer later that day to show you how you can deal with that. Or you may searching for "how to import python packages".